# Iterating through nested arrays and filtering undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array, console

Iterating through objects after running through `Object.entries();` is great, except when it isn't.

Case and point:

```
[
  [
    '0',
    {
      A: 'a',
      B: 'b',
      C: 'c'
    }
  ],

  [
    '1',
    {
      A: 'z',
      B: 'x',
      C: 'y'
    }
  ]

]
```

That's an exact proxy of the data structure in the array 'me_data' logged to the console exactly after running the fetched data through Object.entries in node with `node .`

The point is not Object.entries, but the double iteration that comes afterward, here:

```
me_data.forEach(function(row){

row.forEach(function(col){

console.log(col);

});//end col
});//end row
```

Result of console.log(col):

```
0
{
 A: 'a',
 B: 'b',
 C: 'c'
} 
1
{
 A: 'z',
 B: 'x',
 C: 'y'
}
```

Console just prints an iteration of each nested array and numbers it. The problem happens when you access one of the elements in each array through the two cycles of the iteration (or the 400 cycles of the non-proxied data).

```
me_data.forEach(function(row){

row.forEach(function(col){

console.log(col['A']);

});//end col
});//end row
```

The result for each cycle delivers the value followed by undefined in the next row, and so on:

```
a
undefined
z
undefined
```

An attempt at filtering out the undefined results fails with the error

`Error parsing JSON: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

```
me_data.forEach(function(row){
row.forEach(function(col){

let filtered = col['A'].filter(function(x) {
     return x !== undefined;
});
 
console.log(filtered);

});//end col
});//end row
```

Is there something missing here? Why does the console print 'undefined' after each iteration? How to access and use the value belonging to the same named key from each nested array of key value pairs during each multidimensional iteration?

Comment: Why `row.forEach` instead of just `row[1]`? Why `Object.entries` instead of just `Object.values`?

Comment: `row.forEach`  because it's a large nested array, so we want data from each subarray. Object entries over Objec.values for no particular reason other than to convert the entire json object returned after parsing into an array, in case something else comes up later.

Comment: I thought you only needed the `A` property of the objects. What data do you need from the index?

Comment: In cases where data is missing it will be brought in from apis; however, Object.values would probably be sufficient here also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it prints out `undefined` is because `col` might be the string `'0'` or the string `'1'`. This means in some loops you try to access '0'['A'], which obviously does not exists.

Now from what I understand you are trying to access the object only and not the string numbers.

There are a couple ways to do this.

The first (and the method I recommend) is to write your loops like this

```
me_data.forEach(([row, col]) =>{
  console.log(col);
});
```

In this case, col will always point to the objects.

The second method you could use is

```
me_data.forEach(function(row){
  row.forEach(function(col){
    if(typeof col !== 'object') return;

    console.log(col);
  });
});
```

This method will skip over every element that is not of type `object`

Comment: I like using two `for.Each` because it's clear, but thanks, that's better prod code. What works is adding a condition to access values inside the second loop, `if (col['A'] !== undefined){
let exVar = col['A'];
console.log(exVar);
}` However what doesn't make sense is why that needs to be done. Is the code logging the index to console as well as the value in `col['A']`?

Comment: @F.Certainly. Yes, sorry I was a bit confused as to what. the end. goal was, but. checking `if (col['A'] !== undefined)` should also work.

Comment: @F.Certainly. As for why that needs to be done is because when you access row you are actually accessing the inner arrays. That means the second for loop is looping over `['0', {A:'a', B:'b', C:'c'}]`. This means the first time you loop `col = '0'` and the second time `col = {A:'a', B:'b', C:'c'}`. Because of this accessing `col['A']` returns undefined through the first loop as `'0'['A']` is does not exists.

Comment: So col is a pointer listed as a string? That would be interesting, if it wasn't a tiny bit annoying:) The first method has grown on me, though it doesn't exactly make sense passing in an array as arguments, if that's legal why couldn't one pass in a nested array of arguments?

Comment: I stand corrected, it's not a string pointer but the first iteration of a double iteration. That's clear.

Comment: @F.Certainly. The first method I showed is definitely confusing to understand at first but it works great with entries. Since `Object.entries(object)` will always return an array with embedded arrays of length 2 (it will look something like `[ [key1, value1], [key2, value2] ... [keyN, valueN] ]` the first method is saying. For each embedded array (which we know has length 2) the first element will be called `row` and the second will be called `col`. By clearly giving the elements names you will then be able to simply reference them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `me_data` structure of an array of arrays with indexes and objects, I'd suggest you transform the data once more. If you 'unwrap those inner arrays that are just packaging an index with the data objects, you'll have a much easier time. This snippet shows how you can access data via index, key, or index and key, after the transformation.

```js
const me_data = [
  [
    '0',
    {
      A: 'a',
      B: 'b',
      C: 'c'
    }
  ],

  [
    '1',
    {
      A: 'z',
      B: 'x',
      C: 'y'
    }
  ]

]


const transformed_me_data = me_data.map(arr => arr[1])

console.log('transformed_me_data:', transformed_me_data)

console.log('[0]:', transformed_me_data[0])
console.log('[1]:', transformed_me_data[1])

console.log('A:', transformed_me_data.map(obj => obj.A))
console.log('B:', transformed_me_data.map(obj => obj.B))
console.log('C:', transformed_me_data.map(obj => obj.C))

console.log('[0].A:', transformed_me_data[0].A)
console.log('[0].B:', transformed_me_data[0].B)
console.log('[0].C:', transformed_me_data[0].C)
console.log('[1].A:', transformed_me_data[1].A)
console.log('[1].B:', transformed_me_data[1].B)
console.log('[1].C:', transformed_me_data[1].C)
```

Comment: This is an interesting way of flattening the data.